# Proof that elastance matrix is invertible

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, matrix-elements

I was reading this [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-07-electromagnetism-ii-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT8_07F12_ln4.pdf) from MIT OCW on capacitance . 
It says

> $V_i =\sum_j P_{ij}Q_{j} $ where the constants $P_{ij}$ are determined
>   by the geometry of the conductors. 
>  This matrix can be inverted,
>   so we can write $Q_i =\sum_j C_{ij}V_{j} $ 
>  where as a matrix, $$
>  \textbf{C} = \textbf{ P}^{-1} $$ , or equivalently $C_{ij}P_{jk} =
> > δ_{ik}$ .

How can we say by certainity that the matrix $\textbf{C}$ will be invertible(I don't doubt the validity, just wondering how to prove)?
Is there any theorem or proof for it?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the internal electrostatic energy in a system of conductors, one can prove that those two matrices are positive-definite and, hence, invertible.

A detailed derivation of the properties of the elements of the capacitance matrix can be found in

R. M. Fano, L. J. Chu, and R. B. Adler, *Electromagnetic fields, energy, and forces*, MIT Press, 1968.

Here, I'll just sketch the idea.  The electrostatic energy $U$ of a system of $n$ charged conductors is given by

$$U = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n Q_iV_i = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}Q_iQ_j = \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{Q}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{Q},$$

where $\boldsymbol{Q} = (Q_1,\ldots,Q_n)^\mathrm{T}$ and $\mathrm{T}$ denotes transposition.

Since the electrostatic energy is always positive, $U\ge 0$, and since it can be shown that $P_{ij} = P_{ji}$ (reciprocity), the above equation implies that $\boldsymbol{P}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. Excluding the degenerate case where all the elements are zero, $\boldsymbol{P}$ is positive definite.

A positive definite matrix has positive eigenvalues and it is thus invertible. In fact, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\boldsymbol{P}$ with eigenvector $\boldsymbol{Q}$ we have $2U = \boldsymbol{Q}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{Q} = \lambda \boldsymbol{Q}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{Q} = \lambda ||\boldsymbol{Q}||^2>0$, from which $\lambda > 0$.

More on the invertibility of positive definite matrices can be found in a linear algebra book, e.g.,

S. Roman, *Advanced linear algebra*, Springer, 1992.